# Dual boot Windows 8.1 Ubuntu EFI GPT: rEFInd won't start automatically

Tags: boot, windows-8, uefi, gpt, refind

My machine is an HP DM1-4341sa netbook which came with Windows 8.  I've since wiped the disk, changed the disk type to GPT and clean installed Windows 8.1 from ISO, leaving space at the end of the partition to install Linux.

I tried many thing and read many posts, including the excellent rodsbooks.com website.  I've tried Mint 17 and now Kubuntu 14.10.

I installed Kubuntu (Mint previously) and at the end of the install I received an error message about Grub.  I tried boot-repair but that also didn't work.

After reading the EFI boot loaders section on rodsbooks I decided to install rEFInd on a USB flash drive.  This worked and I could successfully boot into Kubuntu from this boot loader.  I then installed rEFInd using apt-get.  I thought I was almost there.

I tried renaming my grubx64.efi to bootmgfw.efi in all the folders mentioned on the rodsbooks [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#naming) but still I can't get my machine to start the rEFInd at boot up.  If I don't press escape during the boot process I always get Windows.

I have never seen the Grub menu whatever I have done.

Answer (score 1):

Simply renaming both `bootx64.efi` in the `EFI/Boot` folder and `bootmgfw.efi` in `EFI/Microsoft/Boot` (adding a `.bak` extension for example) so that the firmware could not find either of its default options caused it to use `grubx64.efi` which is the rEFInd bootloader on this machine.

Comment: It isn't really clear to me what you have done. Rename the bootloaders/efi-binaries to what? Where on the ESP is refind in your case? A file listing with the neccessary parts and `efibootmgr -v` output would help understanding your answer.